# Can "our Cokes" be simply "Cokes"?

Tags: grammar

The original sentence is:

> There we ate hamburgers and drank our Cokes.

Is it grammatically correct to drop the "our" and say:

> There we ate hamburgers and drank Cokes.

Why or why not? Would such a sentence be acceptable as informal speech?

Comment: You seem to be perfectly fine with just "hamburgers" and not "our hamburgers" why should "Cokes" be any different?

Comment: If they aren't your hamburgers, there's no reason they should be your cokes.

Comment: If they aren't your hamburgers, there's no reason to eat them. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence reads a bit more melodically, and places emphasis on "Cokes", implying that you lingered over the Cokes, perhaps having a discussion as you finished them.  Omitting "our" entirely is more sterile, while using "our" in both places implies a sort of mechanical behavior.

The presence or absence of a word such as "our" in situations like this may not change the literal meaning of a sentence, but it can very easily change the implications that sentence carries.

Answer (score -1):

Such a sentence is definitely acceptable. In the interest of continuity, you either want both the hamburgers *and* the Cokes to be "yours" or you want *neither* to be "yours". Otherwise you'll create confusion in the reader: why are the hamburgers yours, but not the Cokes? It creates information -- a connotation -- that is probably unintended and thus unimportant.

Applying the possessive adjective "our" to both or neither nouns is a matter of stylistic choice. It's a matter of simple good writing to make sure you don't create distracting implications by claiming one foodstuff and not the other. Unless, of course, you do it on purpose.

Hope that helped!

*UPDATE:*

I guess I would also say that removing the "our"s entirely would be better than keeping them, in the interest of simplicity: if you're consuming them, the hamburgers and Cokes are (hopefully, most likely) yours. Unless the surrounding context mandates their inclusion, I would nix them. Though, again, you could have stylistic justification in keeping them.

Comment: It would be great if you could find an objective source to substantiate your answer.

Comment: @Helmar Chekhov's Gun, commonly accepted principle from the world's best short-story author: don't clutter your writing with superfluous implications. I could dig through a style guide for you, but this sort of question isn't based on objective principles. Objectively, either sentence configuration is grammatically correct; but in terms of style (which often reduces to terms of simplicity), it's best not to create unintentional vectors of meaning. And it probably says that in The Elements of Style somewhere.